# Open file with Tabris and RAP

Tags: eclipse-rap

Evaluating Tabris developed by eclipsesource, I could create a simple application browsing some filestructure from a backend. Now I would like to know how it is possible to open/show a file's content. On the serverside I created a service handler for the download. But opening a shell containing a browser widget with the URL to this service just does nothing but show a blank page. If I use "http://www.google.de" as URL then the browser shows this site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does the service handler render html? Can you open the url from a new browser tab and is it showing your content?

Browsing files with a browser widget feels odd to me. Why not using a JFace TreeViewer to show the file structure?

Comment: Actually I was using a tree viewer to show file structure. The problem was to open the file in a browser shell. But it was our fault, as Safari did not understand some special characters in the URL. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming release in December 2012 (Version 0.9.0), the AppLauncher aka OpenWith will be  implemented. This will improve showing file contents with an appropriate app - so you don't heed to display everything in a Browser widget.

See: https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris/issues/89